# django-celery process goes to 100 % and tasks are not executed

Tags: django, rabbitmq, ubuntu-12.04, celery, django-celery

I am using last version of django-celery with RabbitMQ Worker on Ubuntu 12.04 Server. I start to have problem with celery tasks before a month ago and I can not figure out what is the problem. I run celery into production with supervisord, I dont know why but there is moments when some of the process that run celery go to 100% usages of CPU and stay at that point until I restart the celery an kill existing process. When this happen worker does not get more tasks and they are not executed until I restart the celery.
Comman with which I run celery from supervisord  is:

```
django-admin.py celeryd -v 2 -B -s celery -E -l INFO
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can add that I've had similar issues with celery. Had to restart it a lot.

Comment: What is your celery config/setting you setup